# Shortcode Not Working properly into post and page

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I register a short code but it's not working properly. When i put the short code into my post or page it's not working. But when i Directly use do_shortcode function is is work fine.

This is what i register into my function file

```
function world_news_section_shortcode($atts, $content ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'section-heading'       => '',
            'section-more'      => '',
            'section-link'      => '',

        ), $atts, 'world_news'
    );
    ob_start(); 


    $world_news = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'posts_per_page'    => 3,
        'category_name'     => 'world',
    ));?>

    <div class="lattest-post">
    <h2 class="lattest-post-head"><?php echo $atts['section-heading']; ?></h2>
     <a href="<?php echo $atts['section-link']; ?>" class="lattest-more"><?php echo $atts['section-more']; ?></a>


    <?php while ($world_news->have_posts()) : $world_news->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="lattest-post-contant">
               <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'image_post' ); ?>
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>

            </div>

    <?php endwhile;?>   
    </div>

    <?php $world_news = ob_get_clean(); 

    return $world_news; 
}
add_shortcode( 'world_news', 'world_news_section_shortcode' );
```

I use this short code into my post and page. But Not working.

```
[world_news section-heading="World news new" section-more="More+" section-link=""]
```

But when i use this code Directly into my index page it's work perfectly.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[world_news section-heading="World news new" section-more="More+" section-link=""]'); ?>
```

Why should my short code not working into post and page?

Comment: did you check if your `WP_Query` actually returns anything ?

Comment: I don't understand